# How do I change where the underline appears?

Tags: underline

Whenever I underline words with letters such as j, p, q, (etc.), the underline goes below the lowest point of the letter. This causes a fairly awful look when several words are underlined in a row. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

This is what I am using:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\udash}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner ysep=1.5pt,inner xsep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[dashed, anchor=base] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }%
}%
…
\udash{Tasks}, \udash{Dependencies}, \udash{Project} %for dashed underlines
\underline{Tasks}, \underline{Dependencies}, \underline{Project} %for regular underlines
```

And this is how it looks like now:

[image]

I would like for the underline to stay with where it is on `Tasks`, and when `p` or `j` or other such letters occur, the line would just go through them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\smash`.

`\underline{Underlined text.} \underline{Underlined text with a p.} \underline{\smash{Underlined text with a p.}}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. For reference, also words with my `udash` as `\udash{\smash{p}}`

Comment: @ChrisMM Thank you very much for your answer! My problem now is that I use the underline as the first sentence inside of a `mdfframed`. When I use `\smash`, the sentence merges into the upper border. Do you have a solution for that?